# Is it clone safe to pass a classes enum to a clone?

Tags: java, enums, clone, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have a simple class that holds skeleton for a much larger, bulkier class. All this skeleton is is a string id, a type enumeration and some flags for options.

I would like to be able to clone this skeleton, but I don't know if the enumeration is clone safe (pass by value). I think that they are not since they are treated like classes (pass by reference). Is it safe to just pass the enumeration into the clone?

Example for clarity:

```
class A {
    String id;
    Enum state;
    int flags;

    A clone() {
        A ret = new A();
        ret.id = id;
        ret.state = state; // Am I safe here?
        ret.flags = flags;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful if your Java pseudocode is attempting to override `Object.clone()`: it's not implemented correctly if that's the case! You cannot do `new A()` without breaking `clone()`'s contract. If your method is unrelated to `Object.clone()`, then you better rename it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An enum instance, by definition, is a singleton. There is only one instance of each enum instance, by design. So obviously, the only thing you can do is copy its reference.

Answer (score 7):

**JB Nizet**'s answer is right. But also, *just in case you were trying to override* `Object.clone()`, be aware the official way of cloning objects in Java is something like this:

```
class A implements Cloneable {
    String id;
    Enum state;
    int flags;

    public A clone() {
        A ret = (A) super.clone();
        ret.id = id;
        ret.state = state;  // Enum is a singleton, so this is ok
        ret.flags = flags;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Note that you must call `(A) super.clone()` instead of `new A()`, and that your class must implement the `Cloneable` interface.